# How to read the data from 2 columns from an excel file and compare if they are equal in ReadyAPI - Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, scripting, soapui, ready-api

I need some help in reading the values from 2 different columns from an excel file and compare them if they are equal in Groovy script - ReadyAPI.

Actually, I need to compare them and keep an assertion if they are equal or not.

The image of columns I need to compare

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, there probably isn't enough details in your question for someone to answer.  Please see this link for details on how to construct a question with sufficient details:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you have a pro license, and thereby access to using datasources, or is that done with Groovy Scripts too?

Comment: Yes, I have a Pro license and using datasources to input the data into the request

Comment: Well, if the spreadsheet is a datasource, it should be a breeze then.  In the Groovy script window, do a 'right-mouse button' click.  There should be a an option labelled 'Get Data', if you click this you should be able to drill down into the datasource and select the first column of interest.  Do this against for the second column.  You should now have two vars that contain the values to compare.  E.g. assert varA.contains(varB);